# Multiple SegmentTemplates in MPEG-DASH manifest

Tags: mpeg-dash

I have audio only 1 second long and 10 second long segments. I need to create audio only representation that consists of three 1 second segments followed by 20 10 seconds segments followed by 7 1 second segments.

How can I create such MPEG-DASH manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information so I'm assuming you mean that you already have media that has been encoded and packaged sensibly (ie already has the correct timing) and you just need a manifest with a single continuous Representation for that media.

You'd need to determine the relevant values for `@timescale`, `@d` etc but in the simplest case you can do this with a SegmentTimeline within the SegmentTemplate:

```
...
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" initialization="$RepresentationID$.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$-$Time$.m4s">
  <SegmentTimeline>
    <S t="0" d="1000" r="2"/>
    <S d="10000" r="19"/>
    <S d="1000" r="6" />
  </SegmentTimeline>
</SegmentTemplate>
...
```

If this isn't what you meant, you need to be much clearer about the media, particularly the timing etc, and what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I already have 1 s an 10 s segments (.ts files).So I am not sure how this works since 10 s segments and 1 s segments have different file name pattern.

Comment: It's also possible to use a SegmentTimeline within a SegmentList, which would allow you to reference each file with a SegmentUrl. However, you're unlikely to find an MPEG-DASH client that will play ts files, so you'll probably need to convert to mp4, at which point it'd probably be worth transcoding to fixed segment lengths too.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward, do you know, how to create mpd file manually? I meant I want to create ampd file for a mp4 file.I'm confusing with segments.what are they?